# Random value without ifs?

Tags: c#, if-statement, random

```
Random rd = new Random();
int question;
question = rd.Next(1,2);
if(question ==1)
{
    label1.Text = "What is your name?";
}
if(question ==2)
{
    label1.Text = "How old are you?";
}
```

Is there a way to make it shorter? 
I need to do it this way, but find the shorter option, preferably without ifs.

Comment: Looks like a good place to use the conditional operator. You might also want to read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: This should be placed here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8):

You can move your strings to an array and index it by generated number:

```
string[] texts = 
{
    "What is your name?", 
    "How old are you?"
};

int index = rd.Next(0, texts.Length);            
label1.Text = texts[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

{completely sarcastic answer}

You want shorter?  How about

```
label1.Text = new Random().Next(1,2) == 1 ? "What is your name?" : "How old are you?";
```

I'm using this to illustrate that *shorter* is not always *better*.  Your code compiles, is easy to understand, and generates the right results (modulo the possibility of `new Random()` being called multiple times in a tight loop).